# Swift: Local notifications seem to duplicate then some vanish

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification

I have a reminder app that is searching through an array to send reminders to take a medication. When the notifications come through, I'm getting a sea of multiple notifications coming through and seemingly vanishing instantaneously and then 1 remains at the end.

My initial view controller is a `UITableViewController`.  I tried placing my `fireNotifications` function in `viewDidLoad` but it didn't seem to send any notifications.  If I put the `fireNotifications` function call in one of the tableView functions (ie `numberOfSectionsInTableView`) I'm able to get the notifications to come through, but they have the odd behavior I mentioned above.

My code is:

```
func fireNotifications() {
    if NSUserDefaults().boolForKey("NotifySwitch") {  //checks settings to make sure user wants reminders
        for (index, items) in myMedsList.enumerate() {
            let notification = UILocalNotification()
            notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 20)
            notification.alertBody = "Reminder: Take your \(items.name) now!"
            notification.alertAction = "Let's take my meds!"
            notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
            notification.userInfo = ["Med Index": index]
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
        }
    }
}
```

Am I making a mistake in where I have the function call?  Or is there something wrong in the code?  Of note, I just have the fireDate as 20 seconds for testing purposes, but plan on customizing the fireDate for each item in the myMedsList array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're adding all notifications every time. You should only add the notifications you haven't added before. If you don't feel like doing that, you can call `cancelAllLocalNotifications()` before adding them all back in again.

Comment: Is it better to schedule it once per item for the array when medications are added?  Then I'd need to edit the notification every time the medication was edited, which would be more complex.  Users can edit the times per day for each medication and that would necessitate altering the notification.  Thus, I made them all run when you load the app.  Will need to cancel prior ones to do so, but that shouldn't change the issues I'm having with testing since they all fire once only.

Comment: Update - you were exactly right.  I called that prior to running the for loop and they come through properly now.  Thanks!